# flask + sqlAlchemy COUNT, AVG and SUM in one query

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Checked the `sqlAlchemy` docs but cannot see example of multiple columns query with filter and using FUNC.
How to compose a query based on my model to return result like this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(amount)a_cnt,
SUM(amount)a_sum,
AVG(amount)a_avg
FROM public.transaction
WHERE acc_id = 1
AND "traDate" >= '2019-11-20'
AND "traDate" <= '2019-12-01'

******************
a_cnt || a_sum || a_avg
------------------------
3     || 12    || 4
```

Please see below my model, and query functions, one with Class other with session, still unsure which one I should be using in this case. Both result in printing the query syntax.

Model:

```
class Transaction(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    traDate = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    desc = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    card = db.Column(db.String(1), nullable=False)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), nullable=True)
    acc_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('account.id'), nullable=False)
    uplDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)

### this?
    def sum_filtered(account_id, date_from, date_to):
        return db.session.query(db.func.count(Transaction.amount).label('a_cnt'), db.func.sum(Transaction.amount).label('a_sum'), db.func.avg(Transaction.amount).label('a_avg')).filter_by(acc_id = account_id).filter(Transaction.traDate >= date_from, Transaction.traDate <= date_to)

### OR this?
    def sum_filtered(account_id, date_from, date_to):
        return Transaction.query.with_entities(func.sum(Transaction.amount).label('a_sum')).filter_by(acc_id = account_id).filter(Transaction.traDate >= date_from, Transaction.traDate <= date_to)
```

app:

```
@app.route(...)
templateData = {
    ...
    'total_amnt' : model.Transaction.sum_filtered(accountid, f_from, f_to),
    ...
}
return render_template('/list.html', **templateData)
```

html:

```
...
<span class="input-group-text">Total £{{ total_amnt }}</span><!-- shows the query syntax-->
<span class="input-group-text">Total £{{ total_amnt.a_sum }}</span><!-- shows nothing-->
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you're not getting a SQLAlchemyError, then check that the query syntax you get actually corresponds to the SQL query you want. My guess is your filters are not correct. You're using `filter_by` and `filter`, I don't know how this behaves, but it might be coming up with a stricter WHERE clause than you're expecting.

Comment: I do use both in another querying it works ok. I have removed the entire .filter() and .filter_by(), but still the same error

Comment: Does `total_amnt.c.a_sum` give you anything?

Comment: No, Both functions `db.session...` and `Transaction.query...` return the same jinja error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object' has no attribute 'c'`

Comment: You are passing *the query itself* to the template and never actually run it using for example `Query.one_or_none()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thank you. Please post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=text#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text). If no better answer provided, I will accept this.

```
def sum_filtered(account_id, date_from, date_to):
    result = db.session.execute('SELECT COUNT(amount)a_cnt, AVG(amount)a_avg, SUM(amount)a_sum FROM transaction WHERE acc_id = :p1 AND "traDate" BETWEEN :p2 AND :p3',{'p1' : account_id, 'p2' : date_from, 'p3' : date_to})
    return result.fetchone()
```

App:

```
        'sum_avg_cnt' : model.Transaction.sum_filtered(accountid, f_from, f_to),
```

Then html:

```
{{ sum_avg_cnt.a_cnt }}
```